# Word to describe someone who composes artistic writing

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to confirm or consider suitable choices for describing some one who writes artistically. The trouble is I'm having trouble finding a word with the right scope:

- Lyricist - This was my first choice, but after thinking on it, I
  suppose this word would exclude broader forms of artistic writing
  like, poetry.
- Poet - The converse of the preceding problem.
- Versist - doesn't seem to be a word?
- writer - Alas, the vanilla "writer" is too broad and includes prose

Was simply hoping to find a "-ist"-type of word to refer to the entire universe of artistic writing, are there any likely suitors?

Comment: Prose can be 'artistic' too! If you need to exclude prose, I think you have to use _poet_ (which can include song lyrics).

Comment: Can you be clear here what you mean by artistic writing? You are looking for a word meaning someone who writes poetry or song lyrics?  Are you excluding drama, essays, fiction, screenplays, etc? Normally prose literature is considered one of the arts.

Comment: *rhymer* is term that might refer to a poet or lyricist: normally it refers to rhyming verse, but "rhyme" can more generally mean all poetry [according to Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rhymer). It doesn't refer to other forms of literary art.

Comment: You can always say "poets and lyricists". There isn't a rule that every natural concept has to be expressed by one word — consider how often people say "fruits and vegetables".

Comment: You also have to consider people who compose verse or lyrics but *without* writing.  Some rap artists, for example, often compose rhymes extemporaneously rather than having them written down first.  Some Beat poets did this back in the day as well.

Comment: SOED at "bard": **2** **the Bard (of Avon)** Shakespeare

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"*Wordsmith*" should satisfy your needs, except that prose is not excluded.

> ([Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wordsmith)) **wordsmith** a person who has skill with using words, especially in writing:

Answer (score 2):

Based on your idea of 'versist', which definitely isn't in use, you could use **versewriter** or **versemaker** (both could include a hyphen if desired), which also aren't in wide use but would be easily understood by an English speaker to mean someone who writes verse.

In practice, I would agree with @Peter Shor in his comment, when he suggests just using **poets and lyricists**; as he says, "there isn't a rule that every natural concept has to be expressed by one word".

Comment: I'd think a versemaker was a program for writing poetry or traditional songs.